# Change Primary Key on an existing MySQL Replication

Tags: mysql, indexing, primary-key, replication

i using a Master Slave Replication on MySQL (InnoDB) and want to change the Primary Key and indexs.

Is it possible? Just Remove and add the Index and Primary Key??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below simple queries we can remove or add indexes or primary key in master slave replication.

DROP INDEX index_name ON table_name;
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table (field_name)

ALTER TABLE table_name PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY field_name INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;